# ibatis select within insert statement

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, db2, dao, ibatis

I have an select query which sets parameters to a insert query.

DB used:DB2

```
insert into table_name
(col1,col2,col3,col4)
(select col1,col2,col3,col4 from table_name_2)
```

the above statement fails in ibatis if one of the cols returned by the select is null.
I use websphere and hav enalbled trace log,I run the query in my trace log using qtoad,it runs fine.

Where am I going wrong?

Kindly help.

Actual query:

```
INSERT INTO DB2TUNT.WKSET_VEND_ITEM (WKSET_I,WKSET_ITEM_I,VEND_I,GMS_VEND_I,VOP_TYPE_C,MFR_STYL_T)      
(SELECT 7725263,VITEM.DIR_ITEM_I,DIR.PRIM_VEND_I,VITEM.GMS_VEND_I,VITEM.VOP_TYPE_C,VITEM.MFR_STYL_T)
```

Error:
The error occurred while applying a parameter map.
Check the statement (update failed).

Looks like this happens only with db2.is thr anyone who can help?

Comment: I don't understand the context of fail: if it works fine in deployed application in WebSphere, when do you receive the fail? During Unit-testing phase? In another Websphere? What's the DDL of table? Can you post the XML of IBatis?

Comment: Try to explicitly set JDBC type: `select #col1:VARCHAR#...`, for example. This is syntax for ibatis, if you are using MyBatis 3.x it is little different.

Comment: @partlov will that work in db2?

Comment: @alepuzio i get this error while running it thru the ibatis template.the app is nt deployd,v r still developing

Comment: Sorry, I made mistake. I thought that these are parameters. What is an error you see?

Answer (score 0):

in your insert the values keyword is missing.

```
INSERT INTO table_name VALUES (...)
```

Comment: not working even if I add the 'values',the problem is only when one of the columns return null,if it returns a value it works fine.I tried the same statement using plain JDBC,it works fine